# I want to match this pattern "L101"(string followed by three digits) using regression or any other simpler method if possible

Tags: design-patterns, matching

```
 String empId;
```

I want to check if the empId is within the pattern "L101"

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isValidEmpId("L101324", "L101"));
    }

    private static boolean isValidEmpId(String empId, String pattern) {
        boolean isMatch = false;
        if (empId.indexOf(pattern) != -1) {
            isMatch = true;
        } else {
            isMatch = false;
        }
        return isMatch;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i didn't understand how indexOf(pattern) works. Can you explain it...

Comment: This method returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or -1, if the character doest not occure.